# How to replace &nbsp; with white space in tcl

Tags: replace, tcl

I am trying replace the `&nbsp;` with whitespace like 
`string map [list  "&nbsp;"]`. but it is not replacing it.How could we acheive it in tcl script.

Answer (score 2):

String map expects a key-value pair list as the first argument. The key is what it should search for and the value is what to replace with. So what you want is:

```
string map {&nbsp; " "} $input
```